# Totalize empty variables

Tags: php

About this code:

```
<?php $test=$num1+$num2+$num3; ?>
```

If one of the variables $num1 or $num2 or $num3 is set, But it is empty,I'm facing this alert: "Warning: A non-numeric value encountered." To fix this problem, I write this code:

```
<?php 
if (empty($num1)) {$num1=0;}
if (empty($num2)) {$num2=0;}
if (empty($num3)) {$num3=0;}
$test=$num1+$num2+$num3; ?>
```

But this may affect speed, 
if the number of variables is high.
So I write the code differently:

```
<?php
$test=0;
if (!empty($num1)) {$test=$test+$num1;}
if (!empty($num2)) {$test=$test+$num2;}
if (!empty($num3)) {$test=$test+$num3;}
?>
```

But I'm looking for a faster and better solution.
Thank you very much if there is a shorter route.

Comment: you can use type casting.

Comment: If you have a set of similar data, I will recommend storing the data as an array, then you can use `array_sum()`. Does your project have a good reason for these variables?

Comment: In fact, this project has already been written by someone! I'm only responsible for troubleshooting code errors. Because if you want to change the original project code, it's better to write code first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
$sum = array_sum([$num1, $num2, $num3]);
```

Comment: that was perfect. Now there is another question that is almost relevant to this. How ask this question?